# MVC Method to run all time in background?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, signalr, real-time

I want to use SignalR in my MVC app.
The method shoud be like that:
There will be some method which runs all the time in background, and checks if there is new row in database table.
If there is, it will invoke a method which will broadcast the new row and send to the client view.

How can I do that (I guess I need a method that runs all the time in tha background)?
Thanks!

Comment: In .net you can use the class BackgroundWorker for this kind of things.

Comment: It's not working on MVC

Answer (score 0):

Hmm...

If you want something that is running all the time, you could do it with a service, or with a background thread as Rafa suggests - but before you do either I would have a look at whether your overall design could be improved. Polling the database all the time looking for a new row will mean a lot of unnecessary database traffic...

What's adding the row in the first place? Could we get that code to raise some form of event / invoke an action for us? Depending on the database, are row level triggers available to us? Can we use that to avoid polling?

I don't think you should be actually typing code yet, but rather challenging your current design to see how you might improve it...

Comment: Yes I know it's really lot of traffic. There is another way to get DB changes real time?

Comment: It depends on your personal circumstances. Do you have control of the code that actually puts these records in the first place? If so, you could add something to that that launches whatever you want to do when a record is inserted. Alternatively, a database trigger could be used to run a piece of code whenever something changes.

Comment: If you're trying to inform multiple clients that something has happened, then have a look at a technology called SIGNAL-R from Microsoft. It doesn't HAVE to be a javascript client - you can have .Net clients as well...

Comment: I use the SIGNAL-R. But how can I run a thread after I load the view? Because when I start BackgroundWorker, but I get exception:               An asynchronous operation cannot be started at this time. Asynchronous operations may only be started within an asynchronous handler or module or during certain events in the Page lifecycle. If this exception occurred while executing a Page, ensure that the Page is marked <%@ Page Async="true" %>.

Comment: Dunno - can't help you there